# How to stretch list of images with vertical scrolling to fill screen

Tags: css, sass

I have an html code that looks something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
      <img src='...'
  </li>
  <li>
      <img src='...'
  </li>
  <li>
      <img src='...'
  </li>
...
```

And the scss code looks like this:

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: auto;
  align-items: center;


  li {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px 10px 25px;
    margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
    user-select: none;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
  }
}
```

The result is a list of images,with vertical scrolling, the images have their native resolution.
What i am trying to do, is to stretch the images, so that each image fills let's say 70% of the page width, or 100% , whatever.
I tried adding a img { width: 50vw; } , or setting the li width to different widths in percentages or vw, but nothing worked so far, any ideas?
Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FWz4.jpg

Comment: Please make a snipped so we understand the issue better

Comment: add your result img bro.

Comment: @KakSarkar i added the link with the image. as you see , there are multiple photos, one below the other, the width of the photo doesn't fill the whole space

Comment: @JibinJohn just added

Comment: @randomusernamessssss please put your code inside a pen (codepen.io) this way we can edit and make you code work this way we can't understand the problem

Comment: @KakSarkar sorry but this is an abstraction of the real code, which i wouldn't be able to share due to it being part of a bigger project that has multiple dependencies, if there isn't any obvious solution to this i think i will keep looking myself

Comment: If you want some help you have to share the [mcve] without it it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @randomusernamessssss please checkout this if this is what you looking for tell me so I add it as an answer https://codepen.io/sarkarkurdish/pen/ExbmZvv

Comment: ul has ```overflow-x: auto;```. if you increase li width, does it overflow with a scrollbar? then you have your problem.
Double check in browser inspector if there is any styles applied to your containing elements, especially those concerning overflow, width, max-width, etc., if you are using libraries there could be default styles applied that you don't want. Another dirty option is using ```width:50vw!important``` and checking if it changes anything

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the code but in the image, if the image is too small it does not extend to the whole screen unless forced with px not to stretch

but if the image is in good quality with quite high resolution set only `width: 100%;` and everything works smoothly.

If my code didn't help, please update your code and add an image.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: auto;
  align-items: center;


  li {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px 10px 25px;
    margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
    user-select: none;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
  }
  img{
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
      <img src='https://wallpaper.dog/large/994963.jpg'
  </li>
  <li>
      <img src='https://wallpaper.dog/large/994963.jpg'
  </li>
  <li>
      <img src='https://wallpaper.dog/large/994963.jpg'
  </li>
</ul>
```